# Flutter convexappbar screen navigation best practices

Tags: flutter, mobile

I'm a beginner in flutter and i've been trying to implement a convex app bar to navigate between widgets in different files and wondering if this is the best method to do so.

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {


  const HomeView({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  int currentPage=0;
 
late List<Widget> pages;

@override
void initState() {

  super.initState();
  pages = [
    HomeView(),
    const AllUsersScreen(),
    const ProfileWidget()
  
  ];
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
              
      bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
    items: const [
      TabItem(icon: Icons.home, title: 'Home'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.people, title: 'Friends'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.message, title: 'Message'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.person, title: 'Profile'),
    ],
      onTap: (int i) {
          if (i == 1) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AllUsersScreen()),
            );
          }
          else if (i == 2 ) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeView()),
            );
          }  
                    else if (i == 3 ) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ProfileWidget()),
            );
          }  
          else {
            setState(() {
              currentPage = i;
            });}
      }
  )
    );
  }
}
```

now this does work and i can use it to navigate to profile and friends, but i want the convex appBar to appear in all the widgets while pointing to the appropriate icon. [convexappbarimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXDqy.png), i tried creating a custom class for it and calling it in other views but i get a looping error of

```
 ═ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1853 pos 12: 'child._parent == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was:


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3maEf.png
```

should i repeat the convexappBar logic in all the widgets or is there a better way to do this? thanks for any input.